# DKIM in Exchange Server 2010

Tags: exchange, dkim

I need to generate DKIM public/private keys for Exchange Server 2010.

https://www.emailarchitect.net/domainkeys/kb/dkim_exchange_2007_2010_2013.aspx

I have run the DKIM Installer but it was hanging in the process.

Anyone have experience with this procedure? Will it restart any core Exchange processes during the process?  I need to install it on a production system with the least downtime possible.

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't be 100% accurate answer, but I have good experience with this script: https://github.com/Pro/dkim-exchange ; despite of the project is not currently maintained, I should still work on older Exchange like 2007, 2010, 2013 and 2016.

Otherwise if you insist on using solution mentioned by you (and why not - it looks great), then you should find exact reason why the installer is failing. Try to looking to logs in eventvwr or log files generated by the installer (if they exist) or try to run installer in debug mode (if it has this option).

Answer (score 0):

Which server role do you install this DKIM installer?

It should install on the Hub transport server or Edge transport server. I did a test in my lab, and it could be successful on the Hub role server. During the installation, it would stop and restart the transport service.

You could try to do this with an admin permission account.